# Star Wars Imperial Assault tutorial questions

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

1. How do I decide who goes first and in what order players take their turns?
2. Do the rebel players start with any of the class cards specific to their character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The players decide which hero goes first, and in what order they go.
2. The rebel players start with all class cards that cost 0xp.